# A parameter type ruined my Func<shui>

Tags: c#, generics

I got yelled at for trying to use the word question in the title so this is what I came up with. At any rate, this is a purely academic question about parameter types.

OK, so here is what I get.

```
using System;
namespace TypeParamTest 
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintType(1, new object());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void PrintType<T, Ttwo>(T first, Ttwo second)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T) + " : " + typeof(Ttwo));
        }
    }
}
```

That is clear and unambiguous to me (Astute readers will recognize this as a simple extension of an example found on page 249 of [*C# in Depth*](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/)). I totally get what is happening, the compiler says there is some type (to be defined for `T` and then for `Ttwo`). What I don't understand is why on page 65 the example only has one type parameter.

```
List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> conv);
```

How does the compiler know about `T` in this case?

Comment: I'm thinking that the method is contained within a generic class that defines T.

Comment: +1 Good question, solid title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't have enough information to answer for sure.  Maybe T is defined on the surrounding class?

```
public class SomeClass<T> {
    List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> conv);
}
```

If this is an example of `List<T>`'s [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method, then my suggestion above is the case.

Comment: Ah, you all beat me too it! That spark just went off in my brain.